# How can I update this table to remove the datepart from a field?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Some users have accidentally populated a table with a date and a time value instead of just with a time value. I've made the appropriate validation changes on the Access form, but now I need to clean up the table. Below are some example values. How can I write an Update Query to find the rows with dates and remove just the date part?

```
ID    start_time
1     06:00:00 AM
2     12/29/1899 10:00:54 PM
3     12/29/1899 02:00:00 PM
4     02:00:00 PM
```

Comment: What datatype is the column?

Comment: @AlexK. The column is `Date/Time` in the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove the "date" part of the field because there is no field that only holds a time. timevalue is just a datetime where the date is left at it's default earliest value and then ignored.

If you want, you could put a trigger on the column and always fix up the date to make it 1899 even if the user manages to stuff in a different value during INSERT or UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a text field:

```
UPDATE table SET start_time = SUBSTR(start_time, 12) WHERE LEN(start_time) > 11;
```

If not convert it, run the query, and reconvert it back in your database.